# mq fte and ant script

Tags: ant, websphere-mq-fte

Can we use globmapper inside "presrc" or "postsrc" call?
If we can, how to use?

Comment: I've been holding off answering this hoping someone would reply with an example.  I have a new laptop and haven't rebuilt my FTE sandbox environment yet so I can't whip something up.  Since there are no replies forthcoming, I'll at least confirm that this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "presrc" or "postsrc" calls can run any valid Ant script so the short answer is "yes".

Hopefully, someone will respond with a sample code to provide the longer answer.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sample for reference:

```
<fte:filemove src="${source.agent}@${source.qmgr}" dst="${destination.agent}@${destination.qmgr}" rcproperty="copy.result">
<fte:presrc command="antfile.xml" type="antscript" retryCount="2" retryWait="30" successRC="0">
    <property name="source.filename" value="${trigger.filename}"/>
    <property name="source_path" value="${source.path}"/>
    <property name="source_agent" value="${source.agent}"/>
    <property name="source_qmgr" value="${source.qmgr}"/>
    <property name="source_archive_path" value="${archive.path}"/>
</fte:presrc>
<fte:filespec srcfilespec="${source.path}/${trigger.filename}" dstfile="${destination.path}/${trigger.filename}" overwrite="true"/>    
<fte:postdst command="antfile.xml" type="antscript" retryCount="2" retryWait="30" successRC="0">
    <property name="destination.filename" value="${trigger.filename}"/>
    <property name="destination_path" value="${destination.path}"/>
    <property name="destination_agent" value="${destination.agent}"/>
    <property name="destination_qmgr" value="${destination.qmgr}"/>
</fte:postdst>
```