# Is it possible to invoke a antscript in postdst and presrc call in MQFTE?

Tags: scripting, ant, ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

Is it possible to invoke a antscript in postdst and presrc call in MQFTE??

Comment: Yes, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430730/mq-fte-and-ant-script

Comment: @martin clayton Can you provide me the syntax.

Comment: I don't have any way to test, but based on the docs at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/nested_params.htm I think something like `<fte:presrc command="script.xml" type="antscript">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
<request version="4.00" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FileTransfer.xsd"> 
 <managedTransfer> 
  <originator> 
      <hostName>$hostName</hostName> 
      <userID>$userID</userID> 
    </originator> 
    <sourceAgent QMgr="$sourceQM" agent="$sourceAgent"/> 
    <destinationAgent QMgr="$destQM" agent="$destAgent"/> 
    <transferSet priority="5"> 
      <metaDataSet> 
        <metaData key="some_key">Some value</metaData> 
      </metaDataSet> 
      <postSourceCall> 
        <command name="example.xml" retryCount="0" retryWait="0" successRC="0" type="antscript"> 
          <property name="ant.FILEPATH" value="$filepath"/> 
          <property name="antSrcAgent"  value="$sourceAgent"/> 
        </command> 
      </postSourceCall> 
      <item checksumMethod="MD5" mode="binary"> 
        <source disposition="delete" recursive="false"> 
          <file>$filepath</file> 
        </source> 
        <destination exist="error" type="directory"> 
          <file>$destFile</file> 
        </destination> 
      </item> 
    </transferSet> 
    <job> 
      <name>Example FTE job</name> 
    </job> 
  </managedTransfer> 
</request>
```

The properties passed to the ant script are arbitrary names. You could pass any properties in that way. I used postSourceCall but you can change that to postDest, preSource, etc.